# How to find views by tags when view have more than one tag?

Tags: java, android, tags

I need added 2 tags to an `ImageView`. Now I need to find this view by searching it via `tags`. (Please dont suggest adding id since it does not fit my case).

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
imageView.setTag(R.id.position, "top");
imageView.setTag(R.id.order, 11);
linearLayout.add(imageView);
```

I have tried `findViewByTag` by it is giving me `NPE`.

```
ImageView imageView = findViewByTag(R.id.position);
```

I need to perform this `findViewByTag` 2 times since I have 2 `tags`. I need to use both of those tags to perform view search . I have searched the net for several hours could not find anything related to this. Can anyone help me with this?

(Extra info) The ids are in the `strings.xml`.

```
<item type= "id" name="order"/>
<item type= "id" name="position"/>
```

Comment: maybe `ImageView imageView = findViewByTag(getString(R.id.position));`

Comment: I will try that @Lino.

Comment: ok tested. Did not work. Gave `Expected resource type of string` error.

Comment: If you mean `findViewWithTag()` – `With`, not `By` – it's not going to work for those tags. Have you considered just implementing it yourself?

Comment: @MikeM. I meant `findViewByTag()`. I have not considerd implementing. I am wondering if there is anything already existing to solve such issues.

Comment: I'm not aware of a `findViewByTag()` method. There is a `findViewWithTag()` method in `View`, but, as mentioned, it doesn't work as you're hoping.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that-

> ImageView imageView = linearLayout.findViewByTag(R.id.position);

Comment: Unfortunately does not help, Please read the question. I need to use both of the tags to get `ImageView`